# How to run Jquery after Ajax DOM Holder complete loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, mutation-observers

I have page with two tabs; one of them randomly will be active and its date will be loaded by default. The second tab, will be inactive until the user will click it then it will load the content using Ajax. (**never been loaded yet**)

All what I need to do is to fire this code in both tabs:

```
$('#listings').attr('class', 'mobile row');
```

But I fail to make it run in the **inactive tab** as the JQuery always stop before Ajax complete loading.

This is the tab HTML code:

```
<ul class="tabs tabs-hash">
  <li class="" id="tab_listings" lang="listings">
    <a href="#listings" data-target="listings">Property</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active" id="tab_automobile" lang="automobile">
    <a href="#automobile" data-target="automobile">Vehicles</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the content will show when each tab will clicked:

**Tab#1 (Active)**

```
<div class="tab_area" id="area_automobile" style="display: block;">
  <section id="listings" class="mobile row">
    some content here
  </section>
</div>
```

**Tab#2 (Inactive)**

```
<div class="tab_area hide" id="area_listings" style="display: none;">
    <span class="text-notice">**Loading...** </span><!-- This span is loading content using Ajax and JQuery finish before its complete and this content will have new section with the target class need to be changed by Jquery -->
</div>
```

**Once Inactive tab become Active and Ajax complete loading**

this section will appear and the `class="mobile row"` need to be changed

```
  <section id="listings" class="mobile row">
    some content here
  </section>
```

I tried to search Stack Overflow but all the post I found did not solve my problem.

Is it possible someone can explain a way to achieve target?

Comment: Does the second tab have a separate id?

Comment: What is `#listings`? A tab id or an element?

Comment: @Carl Edwards Thank you,I updated the post with the tab HTML code.

Comment: @Colin Cline #listing is other div I need to change its class. and its part of the inactive/active tabs....it Grid/List view... each tab when you will click it will call its view

Comment: This will not work for you? Tbh i became a little confused about what you want to achieve here `$('#listings', '#automobile').attr('class', 'mobile row');`

Comment: Or if you want to add this style to their parents do like this `$('#listings').parent().attr('class', 'mobile row');` and for another one do this `$('#automobile').parent().attr('class', 'mobile row');`

Comment: @Colin Cline, Thank you again, I updated the the coded to show where is the issue. Please note, #listing is an ID for a tab, and #id for the div I need to fire its CSS. and `$('#listings', '#automobile').attr('class', 'mobile row');` will not work. I need to run the jQuery after the second tab content loaded completly

Comment: @TariqAhmed when you click on inactive tab, it just start to load and add some content to the tab holder or just this tab clicks handles to add some `hide`, `show` classes? I mean at first the second tab content is not part of DOM and after click they will load into the DOM?

Comment: @Colin Cline, Yes, When I click on inactive tab, it just start to load and add some content to the tab holder

Comment: @TariqAhmed in this case you can try this `$(document).find('#listings').attr('class', 'mobile row');` in order to let document find new element that recently added into the DOM. Repleace `#listing` with every class name and ids that you would like to add `mobile row` class to them. Put above code inside `.on('click', function(){});`. Let me know if this approach works.

Comment: @Colin Cline, Thank you again, but also I tried this and did not work, its still work only for all active class but not for this particle hedden (NON loaded) holder

Comment: @TariqAhmed in this tabs you load media(video/audio) or iframe? You will add this line of code`$('#listings', '#automobile').attr('class', 'mobile row');` after the code that it's job is to make tab content show/hide?

Comment: @Colin Cline, This tabs just load other function from the databases (blocks and fields) Properties Listing/ Car Listings.... And the `$('#listings').attr('class', 'mobile row');` is Just to control mobile view with the CSS, its working fine every where else, but not in the Inactive tab.

Comment: @TariqAhmed realy stocked ma self :D. If you could provide a jsfiddle would be great but as you mentioned, part of your project it seems to be server side. Any ways you cant handle the effect that these 2 classes `mobile row` has with css? Use media query instead to detect mobile and gave those part of tab content your specific mobile styles.

Comment: @Colin Cline, thank you for your time, I fix it already, but I feel there is better way

Answer (score 0):

After deep search, I found the solution did what I want in [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Which explained there in details, but the short summary its the way to  instantiating new DOM mutation observers with compatibility with all new major browser.

So, If the DOM class, id, attributes, etc... will appear in the **future**  MutationObserver will detected it and apply the rule (**we can stop it any time**) and its support:

- child elements target's
- Attributes target's
- Data target's descendants
- Attribute value
- Data before the mutation (Past/Old data)
- Local names (without namespace)

  The code I used to complete the above target as the following:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
  if (!mutation.addedNodes) return
  for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
   $('section#listings').attr('class', 'mobile row');
   var node = mutation.addedNodes[i]
  }
 })
})
 observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true
  , subtree: true
  , attributes: false
  , characterData: false
 })
```

I hope this can help others and for me this is the best solution for now unless some one else  give me extra help and better advise.

**NOTE:**
The above code, is taken from one post of Stackoverflow posts, unfortunately,
By mistake I closed the tab of my browser, and I coudl't get the post back even by search on Google. I wish if I could gave credit to the adviser with this code, and I should say thank you for both, StackOverFlow, and The code maker.

Edited:
I change the Class attr. code to be like this:

```
$('section.list').attr('class', 'mobile row');
```

As my page include 3 section with the same #ID and this cause the JQuery to stop once he found ID match but not with the Class(s)
Tariq